# Динамическое изменение цвета иконки в Tab

Tags: android, android-tabs

Есть вариант это сделать с помощью селектора, но в таком случае я указываю две конкретных картинки определенного цвета, я же хочу изменять этот цвет динамически, как это можно реализовать.

вот мой вариант с селектором:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use icon1 -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_contacts_e"
        android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use icon2-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_contacts_d" />
</selector>
```

Comment: у таба в нужный момент вызовите `setBackgroundColor()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. Tab, то у Вас TabHost? Просто повесьте слушатель и задайте нужные цвета:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
        public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < tab.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
                tab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                        .setBackgroundColor(color0); // unselected
            }
            tab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tab.getCurrentTab())
                    .setBackgroundColor(color1); // selected
        }
    });
```

Сами цвета можете менять динамически.